# Lines overlaid on ggplot2 bar plot when saved with ggsave()

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I view this bar plot in R Studio, it appears as I intended (this is from a screenshot): [image: intended plot]

However, when I use the `ggsave("filename.png")` function, it appears with light-colored lines overlaid (may have to look closely to see):

[image: saved plot with lines overlaid]

I'm using `R` version 3.2.3, `ggplot2` version 2.00, and R Studio version 0.99.486, on OS X 10.11.3.

Why might this be happening?

Comment: What program are you using to view the resulting `.png`? See [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/p4skgY1QmdY) and/or try opening the image in some other programs to see if the lines are always there? Seems like there could be an issue with the `Preview.app` in OSX? Also feel free to move the information contained in your comment to the question body via an edit.

Comment: Just to be clear, is your second image a screenshot or an actual upload of the png?

Comment: seeing the R code wld help

Comment: @sebastian-c the second image is an actual upload of the png

Comment: @alistaire check the fine horizontal lines within the bars?

Comment: The `png` device has options for `type` and `antialias` that might fix the issue; see `?png` for more information. You can pass them through the `...` argument of `ggsave`.

Answer (score 3):

You should check out the `Cairo` library.  I use it for crisp graphics in presentations and reports.

> Cairo initializes a new graphics device that uses the cairo graphics
>   library for rendering. The current implementation produces
>   high-quality PNG, JPEG, TIFF bitmap files, high resolution PDF files
>   with embedded fonts, SVG graphics and PostScript files. It also
>   provides X11 and Windows interactive graphics devices. Unlike other
>   devices it supports all graphics features including alpha blending,
>   anti-aliasing etc.

I can't reproduce your example, but here's a similar one.

```
library("ggplot2")
pl <- ggplot(aggregate(mpg ~ cyl, mtcars, FUN=mean), 
             aes(x = cyl, y = mpg)) + 
       geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="red3") +
       theme_bw()

library("Cairo")
CairoPNG("CairoCarPlot.png")
pl
dev.off()
```

Uploading the PNG, it looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Throwing this out there in case it helps anyone else. I had this same issue when the stacked bar chart was made up of multiple values, I fixed it by grouping and then summarizing. I think for your data it would be:

```
df <- dataframe %>% group_by(Weekday) %>% summarize(percent=sum(percentage of tweets))
```

Answer (score 0):

This exact issue occurred with me and after thoroughly exhausting different graphics options I found it was an issue with my data itself.  I had multiple rows with values in the same bucket.  The lighter lines overlaid on the bar chart was separating the data, and did not show up in rstudio, but appeared when it got saved as an image.

In your case, I think the following code would fix your issue:

data <- data %>% group_by(Weekday) %>% summarise(Percentage = sum(Percentage))

I'm making assumptions on the variables, you can swap out sum with whatever data aggregation you're looking for.

Comment: Welcome to SO! How does this answer differ from that of @Ella?

Comment: Didn't see their answer until after I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar situation with trying to make a percent stacked barchart. Was able to solve it similarly but used aggregate.

```r
df <- aggregate(Percentage of Tweets~Weekday, dataframe, sum)
```

I then just used the same ggplot code I was using with the non-aggregated data set and it fixed it.